# How to use Java to parse Clojure grammar and visualize it

Tags: java, parsing, clojure, visualization, grammar

I need to parse Clojure code (not really long) inside Java and build a tree with tokens.
is there a possibility to use standard Clojure lib  for that?
What is the easiest way to display these data visually?

Answer (score 5):

Use `clojure.lang.RT` to require `clojure.edn` and use `clojure.edn/read` to get a Clojure data structure from a source string or file without evaluating it. [A guide to using clojure.lang.RT from Java](http://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/invoking-clojure-code-from-java/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint about edn form. It is also possible to get this for with clojure java classes: <code> String data = " clojure syntax here";
  ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(data);clojure.lang.PersistentList  ednForm = (clojure.lang.PersistentList ) EdnReader.readString(data, PersistentHashMap.EMPTY);</code>

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the source code of your Clojure source and generate a graph data structure from it. Then use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) library to visualise that graph.